# Pg_search: Wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

I am trying to add a search feature to my **Rails 6** application using **Pg_search** gem.

I have added the gem to my `Gemfile`, and installed it using:

```
bundle install
```

However, when I start my **rails server** I get the error below when I try to access the application on my browser:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

Here's an image of it:

[image]

I'm wondering what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

The issue was that I was using an outdated version of the [Pg_search](https://rubygems.org/gems/pg_search) gem in my **Rails 6** application.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

I simply replaced the gem below in my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'pg_search', '~> 1.0'
```

with

```
gem 'pg_search', '~> 2.3'
```

which is the latest version as of this writing.

**Note**: You can simply add `gem 'pg_search'` to your Gemfile without specifying a version and it will install the latest version.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**